# Check presence of handler for each type in class on compile-time

Tags: java, scala, reflection, types, compile-time

I have a huge plain old class I have not control over:

```
class Legacy {
  @BeanProperty var foo: String = _
  @BeanProperty var bar: Int = _
  // a lot of fields
}
```

Also I have code which should handle each field properly (user decides in runtime which field should be processed) depending on it's type, so I have a `Map[String, Handler]` which contain subclasses of `Handler` for each particular type:

```
def getHandler(fieldType: String): Handler = {
  Map(
    "String" -> StringHandler,
    "scala.Int" -> IntHandler
  ).getOrElse(fieldType, AnyRefHandler)
}
```

What I want to have is compile-time assurance that all fields in `Legacy` class have appropriate handler object and if author of `Legacy` added new field to it with new type my library should not compile. Or even better a compile-time warning to add a handler.

I think I can use implicit evidence here, but don't know how its resolution should look like. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't have control of the legacy class then there is not much you can do. If you can edit the legacy class then you can look at Joshua Bloch's enum pattern where he gets the enum to implement an interface in his book Effective Java.

Comment: @user3493289 yeah, probably. I tend to think so. I'm sure if that `Legacy` would be a case class I could do my check with Shapless, transforming class to HList, but seems there's no way for old-school Java-ish classes.